# Optimize Video Playback RDPing into VM

Tags: virtual-machine, remote-desktop, hyper-v

I have a Hyper-V vm running on a machine with 8GB of RAM and 2 virtual processors allocated to it. I am using RDP to connect to the VM and when I watch videos or do anything that is heavy in the browser, my CPU spikes and the experience is not good. Are there some optimizations I can do on the VM host or guest or RDP connection to make the experience better? I have tried all common browsers and the experience is the same.

Comment: You need RemoteFX. You've not said what version of Windows your host and guest are, but a Google search will tell you the requirements for using it.

Comment: Sorry both host and guess are a Windows 10 Pro. I have remotefx configured on the guest as well.

Comment: Yes and I am RDPing from another machine on the local network

Comment: Oops, I meant to ask if the machine you're connecting from is also the Hyper-V host, but you answered that now.

Comment: Yea it is weird. It must be a resource allocation thing or what I am trying to do is laggy as expected.

Comment: Do both systems support RemoteFX and meet the requirements? (I don't remember the requirements off the top of my head.)

Comment: I would assume so, both are 2k+ laptops with 1060s in them. Went to confirm and they seem to support it. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RemoteFX